# Inequality. $\frac{(b+c)^2}{a^2+bc}+\frac{(c+a)^2}{b^2+ca}+\frac{(a+b)^2}{c^2+ab} \geq 6 $

Tags: inequality

**(Crux Mathematicorum)** If $a,b,c$ are the sidelengths of a triangle, then prove the inequality:

> $$\frac{(b+c)^2}{a^2+bc}+\frac{(c+a)^2}{b^2+ca}+\frac{(a+b)^2}{c^2+ab} \geq 6 .$$

Thanks :)

Comment: I suppose the last denominator is $c^2 + ab$. Am I correct?

Comment: you have asked so many inequality questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result follows from the method of Example 3.2.3. and Example 3.2.4. in this [link](http://aam.org.in/site/sites/default/files/Basics%20of%20Olympiad%20Inequalities_1.pdf)
(Without loss of generality,if $a\geq b\geq c$,then $a^2+bc\geq b^2+ca \geq c^2+ab$ and $a+b\geq a+c \geq b+c$.One of these inequalities relies on the condition "a,b,c are the sidelengths of a triangle",try it yourself:))

Comment: how do you find this pdf file?it is hard for me to search by google.

Comment: @Tao Hong 洪涛:The keywords are "cyclic inequality" and "olympiad"

Answer (score 0):

By homogeneity, we may assume $a+b+c=1$.  By CS:

$$ \displaystyle \sum_i \frac{x_i^2}{y_i} \geq \frac{\left(\sum_i x_i\right)^2}{\sum_i y_i} $$

Therefore:

$$ \displaystyle LHS \geq \frac{\left(2(a+b+c)\right)^2}{(a+b+c)^2 - (ab+bc+ca)} = \frac{4}{1-t}$$

where $t:=ab+bc+ca$.  Thus, we should show that $t \geq \tfrac13$ to complete the problem.  Unfortunately, by CS, we have that:

$$ \displaystyle 2t = 1 - (a^2+b^2+c^2)  \leq 1 - \tfrac13(a+b+c)^3 = \tfrac23$$

and so this bound falls below.

Comment: For $a = 1/2, b = c = 1/4$ we have $a + b + c = 1$ and $ab + bc + ca = 5/16 < 1/3$.

Comment: Yes, this is consistent with my comment.  The CS gives too low a bound.  y zhao's comment above uses Chebychev $(a/x+b/y+c/z) \geq 3(a+b+c)/(x+y+z)$ which leads to the solution.